# In a Github Action how to reference a private package for a test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, yaml, github-actions

I have written a test file for a Github Action:

*test.yml*

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
```

but my *package.json* uses an organization private repo. When the Github Action runs it fails and I get the error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@org/repo/
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@org/repo@1.2.3' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-02-10T17_17_46_961Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My research trying to solve the issue:

- [Package is not publishing to npm (not in the npm registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589655/package-is-not-publishing-to-npm-not-in-the-npm-registry)
- [Getting 404 when attempting to publish new package to NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115101/getting-404-when-attempting-to-publish-new-package-to-npm)
- [Installing npm package fails with 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520181/installing-npm-package-fails-with-404)
- [404 error while publishing npm package - `npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924422/404-error-while-publishing-npm-package-npm-err-404-not-found-put-https-r)

In my Github Action how can I properly reference the private org repo so that my test will work correctly or is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: I found [this issue](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/49) with some interesting suggestions. For example, using a PAT when calling the `npm ci` command that use the `package.json`, because the default GITHUB_TOKEN doesn't have access to the other repositories, even in the same organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add authorization to on CI with URL + token - it's done through `.npmrc` file.

1. Create a token: `npm token create --read-only`
2. Add it to your secrets on GitHub named NPM_TOKEN
3. Before running `npm ci` create a local file with your token:

   Add a step: `- run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc`

Everything else stays as it is.

Comment: That worked and also made an answer with the complete yml file.

Comment: Step 3 may be simplified by having  `NPM_TOKEN`  as part of `env:` https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71070686/1952287) was correct and here is the sample *test.yml* file now:

```
name: Test
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> .npmrc
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
```

Github Action shows as passed:

[image: jobs]

Comment: I fixed my answer and added “:” so you can shorten your answer :)